# Can I setup Passwordless Authentification in Firebase using phone number as auth istead of email?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, password-less

I followed the Firebase procedure for passwordless authentication:

- from the back back in Python. [Generate email link for connexion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_link_for_sign-in)
- for the front in Angular Js. [Completing signin in a web page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_a_web_page)

And it works fine. I am able to authentify an user using only email and no password. Great ! But is there a way to auth an user using the phone number and still no password ?

This is how I handle my Email + No Password Authentification:

```py
action_code_settings = auth.ActionCodeSettings(
    url=f'http://localhost:4200/login',
    handle_code_in_app=True,
    ios_bundle_id='com.example.ios',
    android_package_name='com.example.android',
    android_install_app=True,
    android_minimum_version='12',
    dynamic_link_domain='magic42.page.link',
)

link = auth.generate_sign_in_with_email_link('some_email@gmail.com',action_code_settings)
```

Obviously, if I change the email (`some_email@gmail.com`) by a phone number, it triggers an error since this function only works with email. Is there another function that accepts phone number for authentification ? If not, is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another function that accepts phone number for
> authentification?

Yes, with Firebase Authentication, you can [authenticate with a phone number with JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth):

Excerpts from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth) (same link as above):

> You can use Firebase Authentication to sign in a user by sending an
> SMS message to the user's phone. The user signs in using a one-time
> code contained in the SMS message.
>
> The easiest way to add phone number sign-in to your app is to use
> FirebaseUI, which includes a drop-in sign-in widget that implements
> sign-in flows for phone number sign-in, as well as password-based and
> federated sign-in.

Comment: Ok, so just to be sure: 1) I cannot do this in the backend? 2) I have to send a SMS to the user ? Right ?